# Under which circumstances is QAbstractSocket::TemporaryError signaled?

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, blocking

So I am implementing a remote real-time control system in C++ and decided to choose QT (which I am new at) for the GUI side. There are more than one computer in my system and basically my GUI will control the programs I wrote and run in other computers through a TCP/IP connection.

I was going over the [QT documentation for socket errors that can be signaled/emitted](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketError-enum) and I could not understand the `TemporaryError`.

`QAbstractSocket::TemporaryError -> A temporary error occurred (e.g., operation would block and socket is non-blocking).`

As far as I understand QT sockets are non-blocking and one can have blocking operations by using `waitForConnected() , waitForReadyRead(), waitForBytesWritten(), waitForDiscconected()`. And naturally it does not emit such an error while using these blocking operations, for it is not an error just the programmer's choice to be blocked.

I thought maybe when the OS buffer is full and one has to write more data to the socket, it may block and one would get the `TemporaryError` emitted. So I tried to stimulate this by making the receiver not receive at all and the sender write & flush to the socket then return to event loop and when a timer timeouts rewrite & reflush and so on.

I saw that after a while the OS buffer is full but now the internal buffer of `QAbstractSocket or QIODevice` gets to store the data  (this can be checked by `QIODevice::bytesToWrite()`: it returned 0 at the first 8-10 write attempts then start accumulating after the rest of the attempts). AND again no `TemporaryError`.

It is important for me to handle all the possible socket errors and right now I don't know how to handle this one, as I could not figure out how it can arise at all. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at the Qt source code and see which native socket errors are mapped to these for your system. This might help you understand it better. You can find the QtNetwork related code here: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/network

Comment: Great, thanks. I had a quick glance but haven't seen the setting of this particular error, but I will dig deeper and then I keep my post updated with useful information hopefully.